# Spring JPA - stop selecting entity before insert

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

*I know this is a quite documented behaviour but I didn't find any working solution.*

Spring JPA make a `SELECT` before `INSERT`. I've implemented `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable` interface but it doesn't help.

This is my base entity class, all entities are derived from this parent class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Persistable<Long> {

  @Column(name = "itime", updatable = false)
  public ZonedDateTime itime;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @PrePersist
  public void prePersist() {
    this.itime = ZonedDateTime.now();
  }

  public ZonedDateTime getItime() {
    return itime;
  }

  @Override
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isNew() {
    return this.id == null;
  }

}
```

**Question**

How to avoid select-ing record before inserting a new one? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using entitymgr.persist() or merge() function? Try using persist() when inserting a new object.

Comment: Let me guess - `merge` ??

Comment: I do not use entity manager manually, I use JpaRepository.

Comment: And what do you think repositories use under the hood? You better show actual code.

Comment: @Antoniossss dont know what is going under the hood and quite not interested. I dont want to change how I work with my JPA entities and I want to remain all as simple as possible. Do you have and advice how to use Jpa repo and avoid these SELECTs?

Comment: I had one  but it seems you ignored it - show actual code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an open source framework, the benefit you have is you can see what is happening in situations like this, so you SHOULD be interested in checking the source code imo :

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Here you can see if the entity is not "new" (which probably means if it has a set id, but you should check in the source code as well), it will do a "merge" instead of a "persist".